# Character transfer from Xbox one

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to transfer my GTA character from my Xbox One to my Xbox 360?

I am not being prompted to transfer character anywhere.

Comment: From xbox one TO 360? don't think its possible. You can transfer from old gen to new gen and cross-console as a one time deal; if you are linked to Rockstars social club account.

Comment: I have a social club account but am still unsure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to transfer from Xbox One to Xbox 360, or any other previous generation console.  You can only transfer "up" to the next generation consoles and PC.  The [Rockstar Support pages](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC) do not state that you can do this as one of the methods of character transfer.